# How do i Combine text of two cell values into one |EXCEL|VBA|

Tags: excel-formula

I have a Excel Sheet

in Cell A1 = '01'

in Cell A2 = '2019'

in Cell A3 I want to display in this required format => 2019-01

but when I used below formula it is not printing zero for 1
it is printing 2019-1 where as I need in 2019-01

code

```
=A1&-&A2
```

Comment: Try `=A1&"-"&A2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **A3** enter:

```
=A2 & "-" & TEXT(N(A1),"00")
```

[image]

This assumes that **A1** is a *Number* formatted with a *leading zero*.